# ECPublicKey generation based on a byte array

Tags: java, android, security, public-key-encryption

I have an `byte[] encodedKeyBytes` and I want to create the associated Public Key.

```
// spec for P-256 curve
ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime256v1");

ECPublicKeySpec pubKey = new ECPublicKeySpec(
            params.getCurve().decodePoint(encodedKeyBytes), params);
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point encoding 0x-5c
>   at org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve.decodePoint(Unknown Source)
> ```

Here after is the whole method :

```
public PublicKey generatePublicKeyFrom(byte[] encodedKeyBytes)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException {

    // spec for P-256 curve
    ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime256v1");

    ECPublicKeySpec pubKey = new ECPublicKeySpec(
            params.getCurve().decodePoint(encodedKeyBytes), params);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
    PublicKey pb = kf.generatePublic(pubKey));
    System.out.println("public key: " + pb;
    return pb;
}
```

I read some documentation it seems the issue is linked to the size and format of the array byte. Is there any way to generate that public key based from the actual byte array or do I have to actually retrieve the params used to create that byte array ?

The byte array consists of the following bytes:

```
a401022001215820e4706de318a40d0bd8648b7907b0283f7445370241ff1fdd77f08d6a598be90222582079767fbe391223f61dcd5e980133a035b4918f6f9de41b3ceb8d801860df8859
```

giving the CBOR encoding:

```
A4                                      # map(4)
   01                                   # unsigned(1)
   02                                   # unsigned(2)
   20                                   # negative(0)
   01                                   # unsigned(1)
   21                                   # negative(1)
   58 20                                # bytes(32)
      E4706DE318A40D0BD8648B7907B0283F7445370241FF1FDD77F08D6A598BE902 # "\xE4pm\xE3\x18\xA4\r\v\xD8d\x8By\a\xB0(?tE7\x02A\xFF\x1F\xDDw\xF0\x8DjY\x8B\xE9\x02"
   22                                   # negative(2)
   58 20                                # bytes(32)
      79767FBE391223F61DCD5E980133A035B4918F6F9DE41B3CEB8D801860DF8859 # "yv\x7F\xBE9\x12#\xF6\x1D\xCD^\x98\x013\xA05\xB4\x91\x8Fo\x9D\xE4\e<\xEB\x8D\x80\x18`\xDF\x88Y"
```

Thank you !

Comment: How can we know about the encoding of the key if you don't include it with your question? There are multiple ways to encode a public key. You can base 64 or hex encode it as bytes are not always shown as bytes.

Comment: I actually have a question about it, why do you need to know about the encoding of the key ? Is not BouncyCastle supposed to retrieve the details of the encoding of the key based on the byte array ?

Comment: No, currently it tries to decode a point. That can be e.g. a compressed or uncompressed point, but you could also have an X9.62 ASN.1 / DER encoding instead. I don't know this format, it seems to have 75 bytes and it doesn't contain ASN.1 DER it seems; where did you get it?

Comment: It came from a long process.I am adding some security to add some session encryption.  Let s say I connect to a device and I received a CBOR structure of some specific data. I parsed it and retrieved the encoded byte array. The data I receive is the public key generated by that device and I want to create a share secret between my reader and the device.

Comment: I cant recreate the public key without the actual parameters used in order to create it beforehand ?

Comment: I understand, but currently the byte array that you are showing is too large to encode a public point, and I don't know what format it is in. You need to know this before you can continue.

Comment: it s encoded in COSE_Key structures based on the spec RFC 8152

Comment: Ah, but as far as I know Bouncy doesn't even **have** CBOR encoding / decoding. I was already trying to (manually) decode it myself given your description but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering how to do create the public key from the COSE_Key_structure :

```
public PublicKey generatePublicKeyFromECDH(byte[] encodedKeyBytes)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException {
    ECParameterSpec params2 = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");

    ECPointECDH ecPoint = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new CBORFactory());
    try {
        ecPoint = mapper.readValue(encodedKeyBytes, ECPointECDH.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ECPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(ecPoint.getEcPoint(), params2);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", "BC");
    PublicKey pb = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    return pb;
}
```

And here is the mapper.

```
 public ECPointECDH deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();

    byte[] x10 = node.get("-2").binaryValue();
    byte[] y10 = node.get("-3").binaryValue();

    String x = Utils.convertBytesToHex(x10);
    String y = Utils.convertBytesToHex(y10);

    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");
    ECCurve curve = params.getCurve();

    ECPoint point = curve.decodePoint(Hex.decode("04" + x + y));

    return new ECPointECDH(point);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bouncy Castle doesn't have a native CBOR decoding.

If you give it a public key point it will try and parse a X9.62 formatted point, which starts with a byte valued `02` or `03` for a compressed point and `04` for an uncompressed point. Compression in this case means that the Y-coordinate is calculated from the X-coordinate according to an EC-specific algorithm.

If you want to create a point to decompress giving the current point you will first have to parse the point using a CBOR library. Then you'd have to stick the X-coordinate and Y-coordinate together and put `04` in front of it, which would give you:

```
04 E4706DE318A40D0BD8648B7907B0283F7445370241FF1FDD77F08D6A598BE902 79767FBE391223F61DCD5E980133A035B4918F6F9DE41B3CEB8D801860DF8859
```

Of course if you could find a COSE library you'd be better off. There seems to [be one](https://github.com/cose-wg/COSE-JAVA) generated by the COSE workgroup, but it looks unmaintained to me.

Comment: I really have no idea what you are talking about... Why should I even parse the CBOR encoded public key ? Are they no easy way to recreate that public key based on this specific byte array ?

Comment: Sigh. Yes, you use a COSE library. If you parse SSH keys you use a SSH library. For PGP encoded keys ... well, you get the drift. Although the COSE library looks unmaintained, I bet that the result is simply an `ECPublicKey` so as long as it decodes it should suffice.